# Заменить одну картинку на другую jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть форма загрузки. Сама загрузка происходит через `iframe` при помощи jQuery:

```
<div id="add_photo_1" class="add_photo">
    <div id="plus_photo_1" class="icon_add">+</div>

    <div class="upload">
        <form id="upload_photo_1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ajax/upload.php" target="frame_photo_1">
            <input type="hidden" name="date" value="29-07-14"> <input id="input_upload_photo_1" class="upload_photo" type="file" name="upload">
        </form><iframe style="display: none;" id="frame_photo_1"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так это выглядит. `<input type=file..` – их пять – имеет вид картинки 
[image]

По нажатию POST'ом отправляем в обработчик, который возвращает имя фотки.

Вот манипуляция в js:

```
$(".upload_photo").change(function() {
    //Полючаем ID выбраного Input
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[3];
    var i = $(this).children('input'); //это импут
    var a = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG']; //массив разрешенных расширений для клиентской проверки
    var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop(); //Получаем расширение файла
    if (a.indexOf(ext) == -1) { //сама проверка расшерения
        i.parent().each(

        function() {
            this.reset();
        });
        return alert('недопустимое расширение файла!');
    }
    // Если все хорошо отпровляем форму 
    $("#upload_photo_" + id).submit();
    //Загружаем ответ в Iframe
    $("#frame_photo_" + id).load(function() {
        iframeContents = $("#frame_photo_" + id)[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        //Если фото загружено 
        var accept = iframeContents.split("__")[0];
        if (accept == 'yas') {
            //получаем имя файла 
            var filename = iframeContents.split("__")[1];
            // Прячем дефолтную заставку 
            $("#plus_photo_" + id).hide();
            // И вставляем туда картинку
            $("#add_photo_" + id).prepend('<img style="display:block; position:absolute; z-index:0; top:0px; max-width:135px; max-height:135px;" src="/photo/advert/crop/' + filename + '" />');
            // Тут присвоем имя файла в скрытый Input[type=text] 
            $("#hidden_photo_" + id).val(filename);
            // А если ошибка выведем ее
        } else {
            alert(accept);
            //$("#upload_photo_"+id).reset();
            this.reset();
        }
    });
});
```

И вот тут проблемка! `<input type=file..` остаётся рабочим, на случай, если пользователь решит изменить фото. Так вот когда повторно загружаешь картинку (сменяешь на другую), то она просто записывается поверх предыдущей в коде, но само превью остаётся прежним. Как это исправить?

```
<img style="display:block; position:absolute; z-index:0; top:0px; max-width:135px; max-height:135px;" src="/photo/advert/crop/image_42.jpg">
<img style="display:block; position:absolute; z-index:0; top:0px; max-width:135px; max-height:135px;" src="/photo/advert/crop/image_41.jpg">
```

Как я понимаю, перед тем, как вставить `$("#add_photo_"+id).prepend(img..)`, нужно проверить, имеется ли там такой элемент. А как это сделать, не знаю, так как мало опыта в jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот и решение, может, кому пригодится.

```
// И вставляем туда картинку

var $img = $('#add_photo_' + id).find('img');
if ($img.length === 0) {
    $("#add_photo_" + id).prepend('<img style="display:block; position:absolute; z-index:0; top:0px; max-width:135px; max-height:135px;" src="/photo/advert/crop/' + filename + '" />');
} else {
    $img.prop('src', '/photo/advert/crop/' + filename);
}
```